jHipster code generator fails in handling entity modification

created a customer.jdl with two fields
generated code using jhipster import-jdl customer.jdl.
Built the generated code, ensured potgres server up and running and the configured db is created
Upon running the service it applied (for eg 20240612174911_added_entity_Customer.xml). This resulted in the table creation
Now I added another field to jdl and followed steps starting step 2 above.
Code is updated to accomodate the new column. However it adds to the same file 20240612174911_added_entity_Customer.xml the new column. Isn't this voilation of the liquibase design principle of nt to modify ones the changeset is created. A new xml should have been generated to add this new column def right?
When I run the ervice with abovve generated code i end up seeing same error.

I see JHipster is adding to the already generated changeset which is voilating the liquibase principle of not changing ones generated changeset. Since its doing that its failing by itself as it tries apply the same xml but with added column as its checksum changes
I want know is it a limitation in JHipster? Is there a solution? This is very common acenario and I hope JHipster being a professional tool should have handled
More info:
Customer.jdl, used to generate a from scratch service:
entity Attachment
{
@Id id UUID,
url String
}
After adding a column
entity Attachment
{
@Id id UUID,
url String,
contentType String
}
Again generated using the added column.
This causes the problem.
Note: I am using JHipster 7.9.3 version

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

The problem is already very long in Jhipster (4 years?), from this reason I generate Liquibase (LQ) changelog always with Maven Liquibase plugin and remove changesets generated by JH. This has other big benefit - the plugin generates LQ config from your customized Java code - with your manual changes  e.g if you use default DB values, or  you modified DB column datatype etc.
